# How disable checkbox when listbox value changes in tinymce

Tags: jquery, shortcode, tinymce

I'm creating a custom popup in tinyMCE for WordPress, to insert video shortcodes, so I have a list of websites (YouTube, Vimeo, Vine, and others) in a listbox, and a checkbox to let the user decide to add the particle "autoplay".

This is a simplified version of the script (the video section):

```
{
    text: 'Vídeos',
        onclick: function() {       
            editor.windowManager.open({
                title: 'Vídeo Incorporado',
                body: [
                    {type: 'checkbox',
                    name: 'video_autoplay',
                    label: 'Executar automaticamente?',
                    text: 'Sim',
                    classes: 'checkclass'
                    },

                    {type: 'listbox',   
                    name: 'video_site',
                    label: 'Escolha o site de origem',
                    'values': [
                        {text: 'YouTube', value: 'youtube'},
                        {text: 'Vimeo', value: 'vimeo'},
                        {text: 'Vine', value: 'vine'},
                        ],
                    },

                    {type: 'textbox',
                    name: 'video_id',
                    label: 'ID do vídeo',
                    value: ''
                        },
                    ],
        onsubmit: function( e ) {
        editor.insertContent('[video origem="' + e.data.video_site + '" id="' + e.data.video_id +'" autoplay="'+ e.data.video_autoplay +'"]');
            }
        });
    } 
},
```

...and this is the window it generates (only difference is the position of checkbox, that i've put at first place after this print:

[image]

So I can get a shortcode as `[video origem=youtube id=XXXXXX autoplay=true]`

But *autoplay* param doesn't work in all video sites, I need to disable the checkbox when, for example, Vine is selected. How can I disable or hide the checkbox when my listbox is on "Vine" or "Vimeo" option, and reactivate it if the option returns to YouTube?

**What have you tried?**

Maybe I'm on the wrong way, but by now, I know a function can be used along with listbox params, so this...

```
   {
    type: 'listbox',    
    name: 'video_site',
    onselect: function( ) {
        if (this.value() == 'vine') {
            alert("Value is "+this.value());
        }
    },
    label: 'Escolha o site de origem',
    'values': [
        {text: 'YouTube', value: 'youtube'},
        {text: 'Vimeo', value: 'vimeo'},
        {text: 'Vine', value: 'vine'},
        ],
    },
```

... will take the value of my listbox with onselect. But I couldn't use it to target and disable the previous checkbox, using both:

```
$('input.mce-checkclass').prop('disabled',true);
```

and

```
$('input.mce-checkclass').attr('disabled',true);
```

Same for "aria-disabled" and targeting 'input[name=video_autoplay]'.
Any idea, please?

### EDIT: script working!

As suggested by bonger, the window can be loaded from a var, so it's easy to target any element. I added some *setStyle* to reduce opacity of checkbox and label when both are disabled, since it wasn't happening by default, at least in Chrome.

The final script, working as I need:

```
{
    text: 'Videos',
    onclick: function() {   
        var win = editor.windowManager.open({
            title: 'Embed Video',
            body: [
                {type: 'checkbox',
                name: 'video_autoplay',
                label: 'Autoplay?',
                text: 'Yes',
                id: 'check-autoplay',
                },

                {type: 'listbox',   
                name: 'video_site',
                onselect: function( ) {
                    var autoplay = win.find('#video_autoplay');
                    if (this.value() == 'vine') {
                        autoplay.disabled(true);
                        autoplay.value('');
                        tinyMCE.DOM.setStyle( 'check-autoplay-l','opacity', '.5');
                        tinyMCE.DOM.setStyle( 'check-autoplay','opacity', '.5');
                    } 
                    else {
                        autoplay.disabled(false);
                        tinyMCE.DOM.setStyle( 'check-autoplay','opacity', '1');     
                        tinyMCE.DOM.setStyle( 'check-autoplay-l','opacity', '1');
                    }   
                },
                label: 'Choose source',
                    'values': [
                        {text: 'YouTube', value: 'youtube'},
                        {text: 'Vimeo', value: 'vimeo'},
                        {text: 'Vine', value: 'vine'},
                    ],
                },

                {type: 'textbox',
                name: 'video_id',
                label: 'Video ID',
                value: ''
                },
            ],
        
        onsubmit: function( e ) {
            editor.insertContent('[video source="' + e.data.video_site + '" id="' + e.data.video_id +'" autoplay="'+ e.data.video_autoplay +'"]');
        }
    });
}
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking though the existing plugins, the standard tinymce way to do this is to save the popup window in a `win` variable:

```
{
    text: 'Vídeos',
        onclick: function() {       
            var win = editor.windowManager.open({ //etc
```

And then use `win.find('#name')` to target the control, eg:

```
{type: 'listbox',   
name: 'video_site',
onselect: function( ) {
    var autoplay = win.find('#video_autoplay');
    if (this.value() == 'vine') {
        autoplay.disabled(true);
        autoplay.value('');
    } else {
        autoplay.disabled(false);
    }
},
```